# (reverse-i-search) in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-history

I usually end up using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for (reverse-i-search), however, sometimes I pass the command that I was looking for; if I do again a `(reverse-i-search)` it doesn't find it anymore. I assume that the current pointer to the command history is before the command I'm looking for.

Does anybody knows how to go back to the most current command in the history without having to click 1000 times the `down arrow`?

Comment: The reverse search is a feature of bash (and the readline libaries), so I've edited the title and question a little to reflect that.

Comment: if you go past the command you wanted, do `CTRL+SHIFT+R` to go back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [similar question on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549810/control-r-reverse-i-search-in-cygwin-bash-how-do-you-reset-the-search).

The best answer there is to use `Ctrl+G` to cancel the current search.

Comment: This really is not the best answer. The best answer is the one given by Dennis Williamson: add `stty -ixon` in your `.bashrc` (or in some other corresponding config file), and then `Ctrl-S` steps forward in history, similarly as `Ctrl-G` steps backward. First `Ctrl-S` keypress after `Ctrl-G` changes `reverse-i-search` to `i-search`, the next `Ctrl-S` takes the first step forward. Then each `Ctrl-S` takes one step forward more.

Comment: or if you already terminated the search (e.g. by hitting esc or an arrow-key), you can hit Esc followed by '>'

Answer (score 42):

Actually, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549810/control-r-reverse-i-search-in-cygwin-bash-how-do-you-reset-the-search/549860#549860) to that question gives a better option.

In your `~/.bashrc` add the following line:

```
stty -ixon
```

Then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to step forward through the history in the same way as you would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> to step backward.

This will even work to start a new forward search (called `i-search` as opposed to `reverse-i-search`) while browsing through history. Suppose you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and type some text of a command near your destination then press up arrow several times overshooting what you were really looking for (or you change your mind). Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> and type a few characters from that line. Zoooom! Straight to it.

Comment: what's the implication of stty -ixon? does it disable something that might be needed in other situations?

Comment: @GregoryPakosz: It disables XON/XOFF ([software flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)), which is useless from the keyboard now that we're communicating at a little bit higher rate than 300 baud.

Comment: thank you, googled for a while and came to the same conclusion, it's mostly useless nowadays