# How can I map page up and down to history search backward/forward on iTerm2?

Tags: macos, bash, iterm2

What I what is to use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to perform history search backward/forward on iTerm2?

I want to type, let's say `vi`, and using that key combination receive previous commands with that pattern:

```
vi example.txt
vim test.txt
sudo visudo
...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "history search backward/forward"? Bash history won't allow the `sudo visudo` on `vi` example (ie. it will browse only lines matching the string from the beginning of the line). iTerm2 on the other hand does not have "forward search".

Comment: @techraf the commands are just an example. If I type `vi` on the command line, I want to using fn+up retrieve `vi example.txt`, then `vim test.txt`, ... and typing fn+down the same but in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use iTerm2 for that. You can add the following to the `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Although it will match only the pattern from the beginning of the line, ie. if you type `vi` then <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>, you will get:

```
vi example.txt
vim test.txt
```

but not:

```
sudo visudo
```

For the latter you would have to rely on bash <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, but that is only backward search. More on that: [(reverse-i-search) in bash](https://superuser.com/questions/159106/reverse-i-search-in-bash)